# Rails でテーブル内の複数カラムから共通のテーブルを別名でリレーションする方法が分からない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

## 前提

Railsでモデルの関係づけをしていて躓いてしまいましたので、ご助言よろしくお願いします。

以下のようなリレーションを実装しようとしています。

[image: 実現したいリレーション]

- `User`は必ず`好きな食べ物`と`嫌いな食べ物`をひとつずつ持つ
- `Food`は主キーに`string型`の`food_id`を持つ
- `Food`は複数のユーザから持たれる可能性がある

ような状況を考えています。

## 質問

以上のようなときの、マイグレーションの定義とモデル.rbの定義の仕方を知りたいです。

## 現状できていること

以下のように`Userテーブル`から`Foodテーブル`に対して、単一のリレーションを張ることはできました。

[image: じつげんした]

ただ、別名でのリレーションや複数のリレーションを共通のテーブルに対して張る方が分かりません。

### 現状の実装

単一の場合の以下のようにして実装可能でした。
これを改造したりして、目的のことをできるのかなとは思うのですが、思いつきません。

```rb
###### マイグレーション
# db/migrate/20211203123059_create_foods.rb
class CreateFoods < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :foods, id: false do |t|
      t.string :food_id, null: false, primary_key: true
      t.string :name
    end
  end
end

# db/migrate/20211203123112_create_users.rb
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :food, type: :string
    end
    add_foreign_key :users, :foods, column: :food_id , primary_key: :food_id
  end
end

#### モデル定義
# app/models/food.rb
class Food < ApplicationRecord
    self.primary_key = :food_id
    has_many :users
end

# app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :food
end
```

rails コンソールで以下が可能でした。

```rb
# 登録
> food1 = Food.create(name: 'orange', food_id: 'fruit-01')
> food2 = Food.create(name: 'hamburger', food_id: 'meal-01')
> user1 = User.new(id: 1, name: 'us01')
> user1.food = food1
> user1.save

# 確認
> User.first
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<User:0x000055730b2b7568 id: 2, name: "us01", food_id: "fruit-01">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

references 型で foreign_key に to_table を指定します

```
#  db/migrate/20211203144103_create_foods.rb
class CreateFoods < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :foods do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
#  db/migrate/20211203145246_create_users.rb
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :favorite_food, foreign_key: { to_table: 'foods' }
      t.references :disliked_food, foreign_key: { to_table: 'foods' }
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
#  app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :favorite_food, class_name: "Food", optional: true
  belongs_to :disliked_food, class_name: "Food", optional: true
end
```

```
#  app/models/food.rb
class Food < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lovers, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "favorite_food_id"
  has_many :haters, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "disliked_food_id"
end
```

Comment: 早々の回答ありがとうございます。
今回、Foodのidをfalseにして、新たにfood_idとしてString型の主キーを設定しています。この場合、上の方法ではマイグレーションがうまくいかずキャンセルされてしましました。


```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
```
```
Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
```
```
Caused by:
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
```


以上が、エラー内容です。

Comment: すみません。教えていただいた方法を応用するとうまくできました。
ありがとうございました。